# How do validators pick transactions to fill the gas usage per block?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, proof-of-stake, blocks, eip-1559

I was looking through Etherscan and noticed blocks vary widely in gas usage from one to the other. I was wondering how do validators pick transactions that they'll include in their pending block, as well as how they determine the limit as to which they'll pack that block.

While looking through this question, I noticed a lot of resources will say desired block usage varies based off of "network demand", but never goes further in explaining how network demand is determined or how validators try to balance blocks towards reaching the target block size of 15m.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do miner select which transactions to validate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83206/how-do-miner-select-which-transactions-to-validate)

Comment: @MShakeG Unfortunately not - I’m looking more for how validators determine the gas limit to include transactions to and how thats determined rather than how transactions are picked for inclusion in a block

Comment: The block gas limit is configured on a network level and determined by core devs based on a number of factors specific to the network such as the EVM implementation used, network size(node count), expected node bandwidth and CPU specs, etc. Does this answer your question:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/139220/86303

Comment: @MShakeG I saw the formula referenced in the answer in the Ethereum Yellowpaper while I was researching this (section 4.3.4) - however, the formula doesn't seem to hold true for some reason, as can be seen between blocks 16923845 and 16923846, as there was a ~14m gas limit increase between the two sequential blocks.

Comment: I guess the terminology used on Etherscan is the "Gas used" by blocks varies and base fee varies based off gas usage - I will edit the question to reflect this